# Return New DateTime From SQL Server SELECT DateTime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table that has a `datetime` column. What I need to do with a `SELECT` statement is return (I think) a calculated column that takes the time from the `datetime` column and puts it together with the current date.

So in the table I may have...

```
[TargetPlot].[TargetDate]
2015-12-09 10:15:00
2015-12-09 10:30:00
2015-12-09 10:45:00
2015-12-09 11:00:00
2015-12-09 11:15:00
```

But what I need the `SELECT` statement to return is (assuming the current date is December 11th)...

```
[SomeCalculatedField]
2015-12-11 10:15:00
2015-12-11 10:30:00
2015-12-11 10:45:00
2015-12-11 11:00:00
2015-12-11 11:15:00
```

Thanks for any advice.

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select CAST( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) + ' ' +
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TargetDate, 108) AS DATETIME) AS [SomeCalculatedField]
from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the dates, after suitable adjustment:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) + cast(targetdate as time)
```

SQL Server can add times to a `datetime` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want this

```
select (convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120))+' '+DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, column_name),Column_name) as SomeInput
```

from 
TableName

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd have to cast or convert anything.. you should just be able to add the difference in days from then to now..

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (TargetDate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES
('2015-12-09 10:15:00'),
('2015-12-09 10:30:00'),
('2015-12-09 10:45:00'),
('2015-12-09 11:00:00'),
('2015-12-09 11:15:00')


SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, TargetDate, GETDATE()),TargetDate) FROM @Test
```